# CMS with SOAP client functionality

Tags: soap

Is there a CMS out there with inbuilt SOAP client functionality? The SOAP server will provide daily updated info that needs to be stored in a similar way to wordpress posts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) supports SOAP, you just have to install the module.

Comment: Here's the SOAP Client module Willis is referring to: http://drupal.org/project/soapclient